# MySQL Package problem after update

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, mysql

I recently installed the newest version of Ubuntu (12.04 LTS 32 bit).

Afterward, I opened up Update Manager and got the following error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:The package mysql-server-5.5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.'
```

I don't use MySQL-server, and I don't know how to fix this. After I get this error, package manager closes leaving me unable to update anything.

Update Manager:
[image: Update Manager]

apt-get upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package mysql-server-5.5 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

**@Rinzwind:**

I tried `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`
`/var/lib/apt/lists/` directory emptied
`sudo apt-get update` worked, and populated the folder
Update manager still has the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mysql-server-5.5` fixed the problem.

Thank you http://www.embeddedheaven.com/the-package-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for-it.htm for helping me.